# Equation for a smooth staircase function

Tags: functions

I am looking for a smooth staircase equation $f(h,w,x)$ that is a function of the step height $h$, step width $w$ in the range $x$.

I cannot use the unit step or other similar functions since they are just one step. I have been experimenting with various sigmoid curves and while I can get a single smooth step I cannot get to realize the staircase shape. The closest staircase function I have found is given in [this paper](http://www.sccg.sk/~chalmo/GM/cagd4-110304.pdf) in equation (18) and depicted in Fig. 4 and it is a close example of what I want (i.e generate a staircase in the range $x$ for arbitrary step heights and widths) *but* it is not smooth at all.

Regarding smooth steps, a likely starting point I found is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535860/what-is-the-simplest-formula-for-activation-smooth-step-function) but it gives a smooth function of just a single step. I have been unable to modify the equation to make it into a staircase. I would like to specify arbitrary step heights and widths and generate a smooth staircase in the range $x$ specified.

Edit (Extra info):
The smooth function I mention above has the problem that the upper, horizontal line is not equal in length to the lower, horizontal line which is why I have been unable to adapt it into a staircase function

Edit 2
Including some pictures 
[image: What I'm getting]
[image: Desired function]

Edit 2
Plot of $s$ with a steep slope showing a different width on the first horizontal line
[image]

Comment: Here's another example given as part of a different question: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028515/for-integrable-f-finding-continuous-phi-and-psi-such-that-phif-psi/2031201#2031201).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a smooth function representing a single step. Assume that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $s(x) = 0$ for all $x < \epsilon$ and $s(x) = 1$ for all $x > 1 - \epsilon$. Setting
$$ f(x) = s(x - \lfloor x \rfloor) + \lfloor x \rfloor$$
then gives us a smooth staircase with steps of height and width $1$. By rescaling $f$, we can get steps of arbitrary width $w$ and height $h$:
$$f(h,w,x) = h f(x/w) = h(s(x/w - \lfloor x/w \rfloor) + \lfloor x/w \rfloor).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Math356 but could you also give a possible candidate for the smooth function $s$? The second function I mentioned is a little problematic in that the length of the upper, horizontal line does not match the length of the lower, horizontal line. That is, it does not resemble a smooth version of a unit step version.

Comment: @user1420 You can find an explicit example of such a function [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) (look at the section "Smooth transition functions").

Comment: the example function you gave has the same problem. The width of the lower and upper steps vary. In the first link I posted, the function has contsant step width for all the steps. That is what I would like

Comment: @user1420 I am not sure what you mean by "lower" and "upper" step. If you look at the graph of the function $f$ I gave in my answer, you will see that each step is composed of two parts: an horizontal line (of length, say, $L$) and an increasing "transition" part (of width $1-L$ and height $1$). Thus, I would say that all steps have the same total width, namely $L + (1-L) = 1$. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguities. Let me try plotting the entire staircase function, then I will get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the incessant posting. When you refer to the  "horizontal line", that is what I want to be of length $w$.I think that you take the width $w$ to be the total width whereas I want the horizontal line to be of width $w$. This horizontal line is the literal "step" on a real staircase. Even when I increase the slope in your function, the horizontal line is unrelated to $w$. What I want is shown in the second figure. The first figure is an example of your function where it is seen that the horizontal line does assume the length of $w=15$.

Comment: @user1420 Even in the second figure, the width of the horizontal line is close to $w$, but it is not exactly $w$ because of the rounded corners of the steps. If you are okay with the horizontal lines being of width $w - \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, you can achieve this by taking $s$ to have a very steep slope (I can add more details in my answer to explain that).

Comment: I you really want the horizontal lines to have width exactly equal to $w$, then I can also explain how to achieve that; however, you have to realise that in a smooth staircase, the increasing parts will always have positive width $\epsilon > 0$. If the horizontal part is of width $w$, then the $n$th step will not be between $x = nw$ and $x = (n+1)w$, as in the second figure, but rather betwwen $x = n(w+\epsilon)$ and $x = (n+1)(w + \epsilon)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36250/discussion-between-user1420-and-math536).

Answer (score 13):

We can start with a simple soft staircase function:

[$$ f(x) = x - sin \space x $$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+-+sin(x))

and then feed it into itself:

$$ y(x) = f(f(x)) $$

then again:

$$ y(x) = f(f(f(x))) $$

and again:

$$ y(x) = f^4(x) $$

As you can see, each iteration makes the "flat" part of the step longer, and the rise steeper.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The period and the height of each step is $ 2 \pi $, so multiply $x$ by $2 \pi / w$ and $y$ by $h / 2 \pi$ to reach your desired scale.

In reality, the curve is only truly flat (zero derivative) at the centre of each step — at every $ 2 \pi k $ — and only close to flat on either side of that point.

Configurability is limited: The softness of the step can only be specified in integer amounts (the number of times we reapply $f$ to itself), and it requires many/infinite applications to make the step really sharp.

Comment: Instead of $ sin(x) $ you could use any [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) although you may need to multiply the result by a constant, in order to ensure the output flattens when $ x = y $

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example based on Math536's answer: [Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20h*(1%2F2%20coth(a%2F2)%20tanh(a((x%2Fw-floor(x%2Fw))-0.5))%20%2B%201%2F2%20%2B%20floor(x%2Fw))%20where%20h%3D440,%20w%3D440,%20a%3D20)

$$f(h,w,a,x) = h \left[\frac{\tanh \left( \frac{ax}{w}-a\left\lfloor \frac{x}{w} \right\rfloor-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2\tanh\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) } + \frac{1}{2} + \left\lfloor \frac{x}{w} \right\rfloor\right]$$

Where h is the step height, w is the period, and a is the smoothness

Answer (score 2):

I used the following function, where the width of the flat part of each step is *b* and the width of the curved part is *c*, and each step is 1 unit tall:

$$ f(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{b+c} \rfloor + 
\begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x-(b+c) \lfloor \frac{x}{b+c} \rfloor, \\
  s(\frac{x - (b+c) \lfloor \frac{x}{b+c} \rfloor - b}{c})
, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

I used $\cos$ for my stepping function:

$$s(u) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos (\large{\pi} \small{u})$$

It might look a bit simpler in Javascript code, using some temporary variables and modulus (`%`):

```
function stair (x, b, c) {
    const width = b + c;
    const base = Math.floor(x / width);    // base of this step
    const o = x % width;                   // offset, between 0 and width

    return base + (o < b ? 0 : step((o - b) / c));
}

function step (u) {
    return 0.5 - 0.5 * Math.cos(Math.PI * u);
}
```

although Javascript's `%` restricts us: *x* must be non-negative,
 <strike>and *b* and *c* must be integers</strike> .

Those restrictions can be lifted if we change how `o` is calculated:

```
    const o = x - width * base;
```

In Gnuplot you can experiment using:

```
gnuplot> f=4; c=1; plot [x=0:20] floor(x/(f+c)) + ((floor(x)%(f+c))<f ? 0 : 0.5-0.5*cos(((x - (f+c)*floor(x/(f+c))) - f) * pi/c))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a smooth staircase function $f(h, w, x, t)$, which starts of as a straight line at time $t=0$, and gets progressively more pronounced steps as times passes, by solving [the ordinary differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507679/solution-to-frac-operatornamedxt-operatornamedt-sinxt)

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}f(h, w, x, t)}{\operatorname{d}t} = -\sin\left(2\pi \frac{f(h, w, x, t)}{h}\right)h$$

with the boundary condition

$$f(h, w, x, 0) = \frac{h\,x}{w}.$$

The solution to this ODE is

$$
f(h, w, x, t) = \begin{cases}%{ll}
f(h, w, x, 0), &&  \text{if } \displaystyle\frac{x}{w} + 0.5 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\displaystyle h\left(\frac{\displaystyle \tan^{-1}\left[s\,\tan\left(\frac{\pi\,x}{w}\right)\right]}{\pi} + \left\lfloor \frac{x}{w} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor\right), && \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
$$

where $s=e^{-t}$, which can be interpreted as a smoothness parameter, so we can make $f$ a function of $s$ instead of a function of $t$, i.e., $f(h, w, x, s)$. $s=0$ corresponds to $t=\infty$ and means no smoothness at all (perfectly sharp steps) and $s=1$ corresponds to $t=0$ and means maximum smoothness (a straight line). Values of $s$ greater than one corresponds to negative values of $t$, and will create a basically the same type of staircase but shifted half a step. (The first case in the bracket has been added because the second case is undefined in the middle of a step since $\tan$ becomes singular at those points.)

Plots from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+h*%28atan%28s*tan%28pi*x%2Fw%29%29%2Fpi+%2B+floor%28x%2Fw+%2B+1%2F2%29%29%2C+where+h%3D10%2C+w%3D20%2C+s%3D.1):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Stair cases of Height=H and Width =W may be represented by:

$$S\left(x\right)=H\left(\frac{x}{W}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arctan\left(\tan\left(\pi\left(\frac{x}{W}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)}{\pi}\right)$$

Here you can observe https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nxmj1yqrph

Comment: That function is not smooth at all!

Comment: That function looks discontinuous, non-differentiable.