# Solution to $\frac{\operatorname{d}x(t)}{\operatorname{d}t} = -\sin(x(t))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, almost-periodic-functions

What is the solution to the solution to the differential equation

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}x(t)}{\operatorname{d}t} = -\sin(x(t))$$

for an arbitrary case where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$?

$x(0) = x_0$ is given by the initial condition, and I know that

$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x_0, &&  \displaystyle\frac{x_0}{2\pi}+0.5 \in \mathbb{Z}\\
2\pi\left\lfloor\displaystyle\frac{x_0}{2\pi}+0.5\right\rfloor, && \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$

but it is what happens when $t \in (0,\infty)$ that is interesting.

The reason I came to think of this was that I wanted a simple formulation of a smooth (with respect to both $x_0$ and $t$) staircase function that is parameterizable with a continuous number, starts from the identity function and approaches a true (hard) staircase function as $t\to\infty$, and [other suggestions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671132/equation-for-a-smooth-staircase-function) either seemed to be [non-smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049337/119068) (i.e. not infinitely differentiable) or have a [discrete parameter](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970318/119068).

Comment: @MarkViola was not trivial to me (I did remark is was a boring solution), but happy to delete it if it so offends you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange and then integrate,

$$\frac{dx(t)}{\sin x(t) } = -dt\implies 
\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{dx(t)}{\sin x(t) } = -\int_0^t dt$$

Use $[\ln \tan \frac u2]' = \frac1{\sin u}$ and the initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ to get

$$\ln\left(\tan\frac{x(t)}2\right)- \ln\left(\tan\frac{x_0}2\right)= -t$$

Thus, the solution is

$$\tan \frac{x(t)}2 = \tan\frac{x_0}2 \>e^{-t}$$

Comment: Thanks! Nice symmetry in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\sin x \implies \int \frac{dx}{\sin x}=- \int dt \implies \ln \tan (x/2)=-t+C$$
$$\implies x(t)=2\tan^{-1}[D e^{-t}] \implies x(0)=2\tan^{-1} D \implies D=\tan(x_0/2).$$ So finally we have 
$$x(t)=2 \tan^{-1}[\tan(x_0/2)~ e^{-t}].$$

Comment: +1, very clever

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Oh! yes, please see my edit.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the equation to become $$
-\frac{x'(t)}{\sin(x(t))} = 1 
$$
and antidifferentiate both sides to obtain $$
\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)\right) = t + c
$$
The initial value of $x(0) = x_0$ gives us $c=\log(\cot(x_0/2))$.
Solving for $x(t)$, we get $$
x(t) = 2\mathrm{arccot}(e^{t+c}) = 2\mathrm{arccot}\left(e^t\cot(x_0/2)\right)
$$
You have to choose the appropriate branch of the inverse cotangent so that $\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(x_0/2)) = x_0/2$ otherwise you'll be off by some multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks Dark Malthorp!