# How can we model a function for this staircase curve having small bends downwards?

Tags: functions, curves

How can we model a function for this staircase curve?

I would like to model the curve shown below and I see four essential parameters for this:

- $a$ represents the bend downwards
- $b$ is the height of the stairs
- $c$ is the length of the stairs (to keep it simple we can use $2\pi$)
- $d$ represents the angle of the stairs

The picture is a schematic representation and the function I am looking for does not have to produce exactly this curve shape and it might be the case that the suggested parameters $a,b,c,d$ are thought too short. How the curvature of the bend is formed, there I am open as well, since a rough approximation of the illustration in the picture below is enough for me.

[image]

I have already looked at some approaches, for example [Equation for a smooth staircase function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671132/equation-for-a-smooth-staircase-function). I already like these curve representations very much, but they do not include this downward bend. Therefore I would be very grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Is x - sin(x) - ((1 - cos(x))^10)/200 close enough?

Comment: It looks almost really good. Would it be possible to make the plateaus more horizontal and a bit more looking straight? Then it would really looking perfect.

Comment: Well, you can just keep adding, but this approach will never give a perfect result:  x - sin(x) - 1/200 (1 - cos(x))^10 - (1 - cos(x + 1.1))^20/1500000